# Why I cannot edit Referential Constraint and how to fix it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This page describes all steps to edit RC:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456813.aspx

Those are easy steps, pretty intuitive for anyone working with database. However, when I try to edit it, I can change the principal component (as described), and:

- the dependent is filled automatically, I cannot set it manually
- I cannot set principal key
- I cannot set dependant key

The grid for keys is simply dead, I cannot even click on it.

I try to re-establish RC, after I accidentally altered it (by introducing base class for the tables).

**The question** -- why I cannot edit RC now, and how to fix this problem?

One "solution" is to delete all affected tables from the model and update the model from the database (see: http://www.mikelindegardeonline.com/2011/03/03/entity-framework-insufficient-mapping-error/). But this ruin all my other changes.

.Net 4.0.

## SOLVED

I didn't notice missing small key icon next to fields. When I added base class not only it affected relations but also key fields. Without key fields I couldn't fix the relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your EDMX file in the XML editor (right-click it in the Solution Explorer, select "Open With ..." and then "XML Editor").

Then you can change anything. Make sure you go through the entire document; some changes you have to perform in multiple places.

Comment: Thank you. I did as you wrote, however when I get back to normal model view, and go to constraint definition I get error (message is written directly in the grid) which says "not found" (I think complaint is about key field) and warning that this constraint will be deleted. The field key of course exists and is valid.

Comment: It takes some time to get used to editing the XML... Like I said, some changes you have to perform multiple times in the document, to keep it consistent.